# convert curl request into URLConnection

Tags: java, http, curl, put

I have this `cURL` request:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' -H 'Authorization: OAuth <access_token>' \
-X PUT https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/<bot_name>/follows/channels/<channel_name>
```

I need to turn it into a Java `URLConnection` request. This is what I have so far:

```
String url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/?oauth_token=" + bot.botOAuth.substring("oauth:".length());

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
out.write("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" + bot.botName + "/follows/channels/" + gamrCorpsTextField.getText());
out.close();

new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are preparing to open in this code:

```
String url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/?oauth_token=" + bot.botOAuth.substring("oauth:".length());
```

does not match your `curl` request URL:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/<bot_name>/follows/channels/<channel_name>
```

You appear to want something more like this:

```
URL requestUrl = new URL("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" + bot.botName
        + "/follows/channels/" + gamrCorpsTextField.getText());
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth <access_token>");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(false);
```

That sets up a "`URLConnection` request" equivalent to the one the `curl` command will issue, as requested.  From there you get the response code, read response headers and body, and so forth via the `connection` object.

Comment: Thanks! I added `connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", connection.getContentLength()+"");` as well, but now it is throwing a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected` error. Any idea why?

Comment: You can no longer set request properties after performing any operation that requires the HTTP request to be sent.  One such operation is `getContentLength()`, as that retrieves the length of the *response* content.  You should anyway not need to directly set the content length of the *request*.  Just use `doOutput(true)`, and write the request body via the connection's `OutputStream`.